# Replace UITableViewController MasterView in UISplitViewController with UITabBarViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, appdelegate

I'm working on a project that requires UIsplitViewController, but I need the rootViewController to be UITabViewController not UITableViewController I'm using storyboard which allows me to display the UITabViewController but when I'm trying to send data to DetailViewControler using delegate DetailViewController not responding, is there any solution for that I've been trying for over 1 month to find a way I can't find anything.

```
FirstTabViewController *firsTab = [[FirstTabViewController alloc] init]; 
UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; 
tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:firsTab]; 
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *) self.window.rootViewController; 
tabBar = (UITabBarController *)[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; 
splitViewController.delegate = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
```

Comment: Show the code where you set the delegate.

Comment: FirstTabViewController *firsTab = [[FirstTabViewController alloc] init];    
UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];   
tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:firsTab];
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *) self.window.rootViewController;
tabBar = (UITabBarController *)[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; splitViewController.delegate = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];

Comment: If you've set this up in a storyboard, why are you instantiating the tab bar controller and one of its content controllers in the app delegate? Do you not make these in the storyboard?

Comment: Well I'm able to display the views correctly in my emulator but when I try to send some value from some TabView to DetailViewController nothing is happening I used custom delegate and I tried separate class to send value all didn't work but if I will replace TabBarController with SingleViewController I'm able to send values to DetailViewController but I need TabBarController is there anyway to make it work I tried delegate and NSNotification Center and all fail to send some action to DetailViewController.

Comment: It would be helpful to post a picture of your storyboard, or describe it fully.

Comment: Well thank you for your replies anyway I could not upload pictures because I need more than 10 reputation, but I was able to solve my problem which was very easy very bad that I wasted so much time working around this issue and finally it was super easy I solved it by creating MasterView application which is the apple template for UISplitViewController and I copied the method they use to send data between rootViewController and DetailViewController and it works just fine thank you for your help anyway appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppDelegate.m applicationDidFinishLaunch add these lines of codes and return YES

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
```

TabOneViewController.h add these lines of codes:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DetailViewController;

@interface TabOneViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) DetailViewController *detailViewController;

- (IBAction)SendData:(id)sender;
@end
```

TabOneViewController.m add these codes:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
```

in viewDidLoad add This Line of Code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // this code is very very important.
    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}
```

in the button action method add this line of code:

```
- (IBAction)SendData:(id)sender {
self.detailViewController.detailItem = @"Hello From First Tab";
```

}

In DetailViewController Do the following:
in The .h file add these properties

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
```

in the .m file add the following

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = self.detailItem;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // call the configureView method
    [self configureView];
}
```

now on any additional view added to the Left Panel you have to copy the code written in TabOneController and it should work

Done now it works on any kind of controllers very easy solution took me over a month to solve it hope it helps you guys.